# How to go through a list without using a "for i" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

When the function gets called, the *args are a tuple so I have to append each argument to a list first. Then I sum them by mapping their values to float and using the sum() function.

There is nothing wrong whith this block of code, but I get a warning saying "Unused variable i".

```
def function(*args):
    x = []
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(args)):
        x.append(args[y])
        y += 1
   x = list(map(float, x))
   return sum(x)
```

Is there a way to do this in some other way that doesn't envolve using a "for i" loop and is more efficient?

Comment: `range(len(something))` is almost always the wrong thing to do in Python. Always iterate over the thing itself: `for y in args`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why do you have to append each argument to a list? `map` accepts more than just lists. You can give it tuples, too, among other things. `map(float, args)` should work fine.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Your are doing nothing wrong, but you could do better. BTW at the time of append, `i` and `y` will always be the same value. But it will be faster if you use e.g. `return sum(map(float, args))`

Comment: @DanielRoseman save for some exceptions like when you want to extract subsets (e.g. `'abcd'` to `'ab'`, `'bc'`, `'cd'`) and want to iterate through `len - x` to avoid `IndexError`. :)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pythonic way would be something like this:

```
def function(*args):
    return sum(float(x) for x in args)
```

Now, for explaining all this over your code. You can avoid using the variable `y` because it is doing exactly the same as `i`:

```
def function(*args):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(args)):
        x.append(args[i])
    x = list(map(float, x))
    return sum(x)
```

And then, you can avoid appending because you can use `map` over `args`:

```
def function(*args):
    x = list(map(float, args))
    return sum(x)
```

You can also just use `map(float, args)`, no need to create an intermediate list for this purpouse:

```
def function(*args):
    x = map(float, args)
    return sum(x)
```

So it can be abstract as a generator inside `sum`, `sum(float(x) for x in args)`, or with map `sum(map(float, args))`, same effect there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to introduce `y` when `i` is already doing the job for you:

```
def function(*args):
    x = []
    # y = 0 <-- This is not necessary
    for i in range(len(args)):
        x.append(args[i])   # <-- change to [i]
        # y += 1
        # i increments by 1 each loop.
    x = list(map(float, x))
    return sum(x)
```

Of course, you can further reduce this function by looping directly through `args` instead of the `range` of it:

```
def function(*args):
    x = []
    for arg in args:
    # directly loops through the elements within your args
        x.append(arg)
    x = list(map(float, x))
    return sum(x)
```

You might even want to combine the `float` operation while you append to avoid the `map` afterwards:

```
def function(*args):
    x = []
    for arg in args:
        x.append(float(arg))
    return sum(x)
```

What's more, you can make use of list comprehension to make this even shorter:

```
def function(*args):
    x = [float(arg) for arg in args]
    # does the same thing as above
    return sum(x)
```

Or, just combine everything into one line:

```
def function(*args):
    return sum(float(arg) for arg in args)
```

Of course, depending on the complexity of your requirement, you might want to validate each elements before you cast them as `floats` via `try... except` blocks.

Comment: well, this is a coincidence I guess...

Comment: What did you eat to type so fast... now I look the complete fool.

Comment: Netwave's hands...are not idle. You're at a serious disadvantage here.

Comment: Here comes the downvotes! Can't say I don't understand... I'll leave it up for now for OP to read unless people really dislike my answer (which honestly is a coincident).

Comment: I'll upvote it to balance, it doesn't deserce to be downvoted because it is a good answer actually ;)

Comment: Thanks @Netwave, maybe share your power food next time with me too :)